# Self-signed certificates in Electron on Windows are not recognized until after restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, powershell, electron

**Background:**

I use self-signed certificates in my Electron app. I've decided to make sure they've been installed successfully to the trusted root authority by making an asynchronous request to the server on the client side. I use `XMLHttpRequest` to do that.

It works in development environment, but in production the following error is thrown:

> `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

However, the error is gone and everything works when I restart the app.

**What I've tried to fix it:**

I install the certificates with `certutil -addstore`.

To get admin privileges I place the command inside argument list of:

```
Start-Process powershell -verb runAs -ArgumentList
```

`Start-Process` is asynchronous and adding `-wait` doesn't work, even though it should.

The problem seems to be that Electron fetches trusted root authority before I add my self-signed certificates there.

**Question:**

How do I tackle this problem? Seems like the problem would still persist even if I find and implement a way to synchronously execute the powershell command with admin privileges.

Do I have to somehow manually re-fetch the trusted root authority?

Or is restarting the app is the only way to solve the problem?

Comment: It's the same with Chrome, so restarting the app is likely the only way.

Comment: A quick search for "Electron reload trusted certs" yields no interesting result. I can't say it's impossible, but I'd reckon it's at least way harder than reloading the app.